# How to fix flow type length error in array?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, flow-typed

Let say my code like below

```
//@flow
type something = (input:Array<{data:?number}|{data<Object>}>) => boolean

function some:something(own){
 if(!own[0].data.length)
  return false
}
```

i got message:
property `length`,
Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
null or undefined

how to fixed that?
because in function some can be parsing
 1. Array with inside object or maybe not object.
 2. Array with inside Object and in Object can be data with Array of Object or Array of null/undefine
 3. how declare length in flow type if like that

Comment: The provided example is not even close to valid flow syntax, you would be receiving a long list of errors. Please ensure the accuracy of the example and provide a copy of the error output.

Answer (score 0):

flow gives you an error because you try to access property `length` on `data` - which you declared may be undefined... so you need to "instruct" flow that you checked against that:

```
function some:something(own){
 if(own[0].data && !own[0].data.length) // if an data property exists AND is not an array
  return false
}
```

btw if you just try to check whether `own[0].data` is an array just do:

```
if(Array.isArray(own[0].data)) {
```